# UIBezierPath not drawing on correct border of UIViews in iPhone 6/6+

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uibezierpath

I have a class that I've used for a long time that draws a border around a `UIView` (or anything that inherits from `UIView`) and give that view rounded corners. I was doing some testing today (after upgrading to Xcode 7 and compiling on iOS 8.3 for the first time) and noticed that the right edge of the UIView is being truncated when I run on iPhone 6/6+ on the simulator (I don't have the actual devices, but I assume the results would be the same).

Here is a simple example. Notice how I've given the superview a red background to make this jump out. The subview is a UIView that has a fixed height and is vertically aligned to the center of the view. That works. The leading and trailing edges are supposed to be pinned to the edge of the superview, as you can see in the constraints in this image. Notice how the inner `UILabel` and `UIButton` are centered as they should be, but the `UIView` container is getting truncated on the right, even though the border is being drawn.

[image]

Here are the storyboard settings. The `UIView` that has the borders is of a fixed height, centered vertically, with leading and trailing edges pinned to the superview:

[image]

And finally, here is the code. In the `UIViewController`, I ask for borders like this. If I comment this code out, the view looks just fine, other than I don't have the borders that I want, of course.

```
BorderMaker *borderMaker = [[BorderMaker alloc] init];
[borderMaker makeBorderWithFourRoundCorners:_doneUpdatingView borderColor:[SharedVisualElements primaryFontColor] radius:8.0f];
```

And the BorderMaker class:

```
@implementation BorderMaker

- (void) makeBorderWithFourRoundCorners  : (UIView *) view
                             borderColor : (UIColor *) borderColor
                                  radius : (CGFloat) radius
{
    UIRectCorner corners = UIRectCornerAllCorners;
    CGSize radii = CGSizeMake(radius, radius);
    [self drawBorder : corners
         borderColor : borderColor
                view : view
               radii : radii];
}


- (void) drawBorder : (UIRectCorner) corners
        borderColor : (UIColor *) borderColor
               view : (UIView *) view
              radii : (CGSize) radii
{

    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:view.bounds
                                               byRoundingCorners:corners
                                                     cornerRadii:radii];

    // Mask the container view’s layer to round the corners.
    CAShapeLayer *cornerMaskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    [cornerMaskLayer setPath:path.CGPath];
    view.layer.mask = cornerMaskLayer;

    // Make a transparent, stroked layer which will dispay the stroke.
    CAShapeLayer *strokeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    strokeLayer.path = path.CGPath;
    strokeLayer.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    strokeLayer.strokeColor = borderColor.CGColor;
    strokeLayer.lineWidth = 1.5; // the stroke splits the width evenly inside and outside,
    // but the outside part will be clipped by the containerView’s mask.

    // Transparent view that will contain the stroke layer
    UIView *strokeView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:view.bounds];
    strokeView.userInteractionEnabled = NO; // in case your container view contains controls
    [strokeView.layer addSublayer:strokeLayer];

    // configure and add any subviews to the container view

    // stroke view goes in last, above all the subviews
    [view addSubview:strokeView];

}
```

Somewhere in that class, it seems that the views bounds are not reflecting the fact that AutoLayout has stretched the view to fill the larger iPhone 6/6+ screen width. Just a guess since I am out of ideas. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

BorderMaker creates various layers and views based on the current size of the input view. How do those layers and views get resized when the input view changes size? Answer: they don't.

You could add code to update the size in various ways, but I wouldn't recommend it. Since you're rounding all four corners anyway, you can solve this better by just using the existing `CALayer` support for drawing a border, rounding the corners, and masking its contents.

Here's a simple `BorderView` class:

#### BorderView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

IB_DESIGNABLE
@interface BorderView : UIView

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBInspectable UIColor *borderColor;
@property (nonatomic) IBInspectable CGFloat borderWidth;
@property (nonatomic) IBInspectable CGFloat cornerRadius;

@end
```

#### BorderView.m

```
#import "BorderView.h"

@implementation BorderView

- (void)setBorderColor:(UIColor *)borderColor {
    self.layer.borderColor = borderColor.CGColor;
}

- (UIColor *)borderColor {
    CGColorRef cgColor = self.layer.borderColor;
    return cgColor ? [UIColor colorWithCGColor:self.layer.borderColor] : nil;
}

- (void)setBorderWidth:(CGFloat)borderWidth {
    self.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth;
}

- (CGFloat)borderWidth {
    return self.layer.borderWidth;
}

- (void)setCornerRadius:(CGFloat)cornerRadius {
    self.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius;
}

- (CGFloat)cornerRadius {
    return self.layer.cornerRadius;
}

@end
```

Now, if you create a view in your storyboard and set its custom class to `BorderView`, you can set up its border right in the storyboard:

[image: interface builder]

Note that I set “Clip Subviews” in the storyboard, so it'll clip subviews if they happen to go outside the rounded bounds of the `BorderView`.

If you set up constraints on the `BorderView`, they'll keep everything sized and positioned:

[image: simulator rotating]

Comment: Wow. Thanks for the detailed response. The problem that I have is that I have many dozens of various UIViews (text fields, views, scollviews, etc.), and it would probably take me an entire day to migrate them all to an entirely new class. if I need to, I will, but for the purposes of this app, my preference is to find a way to modify the BorderMaker class to handle this, if that is at all possible. Thanks again! Great suggestion. I don't understand why the frame passed over to the bezier class by auto layout isn't the final frame that gets rendered on the screen.

Comment: Presumably auto layout hasn't run by the time you're setting up the border. Anyway, you can set the `borderColor`, `borderWidth`, and `cornerRadius` properties on any view's layer. So you could modify `BorderMaker` to do that instead of what it does now.

Comment: One problem that I have in implementing this suggestion is that I use this BorderMaker class on many different types of views. So I don't know what this class inherits from. If it inherits from UIView, then my UITextFields can't be a subclass of it. If it inherits from UITextField, then my UIScrollView can't be a subclass of it. And so on. I don't know how to work around that issue (other than to make a class like this for every type of view I want to draw a border around).

Answer (score 1):

I solved this. The problem is that I was calling these `BorderMaker` methods from within the `viewDidLoad` method of the `UIViewController`. All I had to do was to move this to `viewDidAppear`. Presumably, as Rob Mayoff suggested, the autolayout wasn't finished by the time that the view was passed to the `BorderMaker` class, so it was getting a frame that hadn't considered the size of the screen, but rather was just using the width defined in the IB.

After some trial and error, it seems that `viewDidAppear` is the earliest life cycle method that I can use where autolayout is done with its work.

Comment: Actually, `viewDidLayoutSubviews` should work, and avoids any flicker of the views appearing onscreen without borders for an instant.